# Differentiability without limits

Tags: limits, analysis, derivatives

There are four concepts which are studied in Calculus and Analysis: Convergence, Continuity, Differentiability and Integrability. In Calculus, you can define the latter three in terms of the first, but also you can define integrability without convergence using Darboux approach. In topology, you can define convergence and continuity in terms of neighborhoods, and in measure theory you can define integrability in terms of measurable functions. I wonder if there is a definition of differentiability without making any reference to the concept of limit or convergence, thank you so much by your help.

Comment: In the last sentence, did you mean differentiaton?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your observation

Comment: Since you are accepting integrability without convergence and limits, I guess there's a way to define the derivative like in Sobolev spaces avoiding the "a.e" problem...

Comment: [Carathéodory's theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_Theorem_(Analysis)) allows us to reduce the notion of differentiability to that of continuity. The latter still requires some amount of topology, though.